# When redirecting to home route, how do I render data selected from current route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am building a PC setup helping website. In my homepage I'll have a list of category of products i.e Processor, Motherboard like 1st picture. As you can see I have run my JS code using node js and command was "nodemon run.js". In the address bar you can see localhost:3000 which means I gave it port 3000 and this page is loaded onto my home route.[Image for Home route or default route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O038l.png)

Beside each entry i.e Processor, Motherboard you can see a purple button. Also text saying "Not Specified", which is a paragraph tag text. I will click that "choose" button beside processor and it will take me to "/product" route that I defined for processor products. In /product route we get a list of all products of the category we selected. Second image shows just that /product route page.
[Image for /product route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGWPR.png)

Now by clicking the select button I will select that product on the list. That's where the tricky part is. I want to select that product, and as soon as I select that product, it should redirect me to the home route, where you see localhost:3000 which means I am back to the home route and it shows the page with all the Categories i.e Processor, Motherboard. But this time, as I have selected a product from /product route, the name of the product should show up in place of "Not Specified" text. Remember this was the text in the list element?

Now what I did was, I rendered that data to the /product route and also homepage was rendered into this /product route. Because to go to the home route I have to use res.redirect and that will take me to home route. But I won't be able to get the data I got from the "/product" route and render it in the text. The 3rd image has an area marked where it shows "/product" route and the homepage is loaded into "/product" route. The data I selected is put on the "Not Specified" text but this is not redirected to home route rather it's just the homepage rendered into "/product" route. Which is not what I want.[Can render the name on there but it's still /product route which I want to be home route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zFIe.jpg)

I want to redirect to my home route, with the data I selected from "/product" route, render this data into that "Not Specified" text I have on first image.

Below is the whole code I wrote as an example to make this work. It's still not complete. I just want help on the app.get and app.post parts where I render those data into route.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/productDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});

//Database Part Start

const listProcessor = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    core: Number,
    thread: Number
});

const ListProcessor = mongoose.model("ListProcessor", listProcessor);

const item1 = new ListProcessor({
    name: "AMD Ryzen 5 3600",
    core: 6,
    thread: 12,
    price: 17100
});

const processorArray = [item1];

//Database Part end
//server part and get post part start

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("buildown", {name: "Not Specified", price: "Not Specified"});
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){
    const signal = req.body.choose;
    if(signal === "cpu")
    {
        ListProcessor.find({}, function(err, items){
            if(items.length === 0)
            {
                ListProcessor.insertMany(processorArray);
                res.redirect("/product");
            }
            else{
                res.redirect("/product");
            }
        });

    }
});

app.get("/product", function(req, res){
    res.render("list", {listTitle: "Processor", listOfProduct: processorArray}); //Using EJS passing data from processorArray
});
app.post("/product", function(req, res){
    const nameItem = req.body.select;
    ListProcessor.find({nameItem}, function(err, items){
        console.log(items);
        res.render("buildown", {name: nameItem, price: items.price});
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server Up and Running");
});

//Get Post part end
```

In the homepage I do have a paragraph tag inserted amongst the table data which uses EJS so that the name I get from "/product" can be rendered into that text. Initially it would be "Not Specified".

For the product page I also used EJS so that product name, price, data can be put from the database.

page on "/product" route shows a list of the products under the Category we selected. Please help me so that I can select an element from that list using "select" button and I can take that data, redirect to home route where homepage is and render the data I got into that paragraph tag so that instead of "Not Specified" it shows the name of the selected product.

Please notify me if I missed any detail and you need a more elaborate explanation of what I am targeting to do here. Thank you in advance. Also I am not so sure what to search on google about this problem so tell me the keywords I need to search in google so that I can learn it myself.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to store the chosen references in a cookie? This way, if the user chooses a CPU, motherboard, RAM, GPU, and accidentally hits "Back" in the browser, they don't have to restart from scratch. Then, you can read that cookie when the `/` page is requested, and fill in the components. Allow the user to reset this selection (remove the cookie), and if an order is made, reset it yourself automatically

Comment: I don't really know how to use cookies. I am doing this for a university project and I have to submit fast. I just wanna know how I can fetch data from /product and use it on / route or home route